# Query builder laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

It happens I'm doing a query and still not have the field of condition (where ) and found that maybe you can do it this way

```
$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw('select * from some_table WHERE some_id = ?'),
    array($id)
); 
var_dump($results);
```

But not how to use it, can someone explain me please?

Comment: `$results = DB::table('some_table')->where('some_id', '=', 12)->get();`

Comment: Now if you want to check the id in an array: 
`$results = DB::table('some_table')->whereIn('some_id', '=',  $idArray)->get();`

Comment: You could use Eloquent - but as you have posted a raw query this should work: `$results = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from some_table WHERE some_id = :someid'), array('someid' => $id)); var_dump($results);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = DB::table('some_table')->where('some_id', '=', 12)->get();
//This is to check for an id.


$idArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$results = DB::table('some_table')->whereIn('some_id', '=', $idArray)->get();
//checks for id in an array
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer use raw query:

```
$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw('select * from some_table WHERE some_id = '.$id)
);
```

Although I would recommend using raw queries if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be an issue with how you're `sanitizing` your variable(s) - I don't know much about Laravel but looking at documentation it is pointing towards this approach:

`$results = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from some_table WHERE some_id = :someid'), array('someid' => $id)); var_dump($results);`

Also, are you sure you need to select all columns?

Just bear in mind when choosing between eloquent & raw - if you have a complicated query returning a large data set `Eloquent` could be a big performance hit, otherwise Eloquent is a dream!